# How to create JPanels inside a for loop and change the JPanel Name using String

Tags: java, string, swing, for-loop, jpanel

This is my code for Creating a chess board using JPanels. I want to be able to use the boardArray and use asign a String value to it which represents the name of the Panel. How do I do that? For example:

```
boardArray[1][5] = "TwoSix";
```

TwoSix should be a string value which I make in a for loop, but it represents the Panel that I have created.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.Color;

public class ChessBoardPractice extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    Component boardArray[][] = new Component[8][8];

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ChessBoardPractice frame = new ChessBoardPractice();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ChessBoardPractice() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel OneOne = new JPanel();
    OneOne.setBounds(20, 20, 30, 30);
    OneOne.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    OneOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    //contentPane.add(OneOne);


    JPanel TwoTwo = new JPanel();
    TwoTwo.setLayout(null);
    TwoTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoTwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TwoTwo.setBounds(50, 50, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(TwoTwo);

    JPanel ThreeThree = new JPanel();
    ThreeThree.setLayout(null);
    ThreeThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeThree.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    ThreeThree.setBounds(80, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeThree);

    JPanel FourFour = new JPanel();
    FourFour.setLayout(null);
    FourFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourFour.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FourFour.setBounds(110, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourFour);

    JPanel FiveFive = new JPanel();
    FiveFive.setLayout(null);
    FiveFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveFive.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FiveFive.setBounds(140, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveFive);

    JPanel SixSix = new JPanel();
    SixSix.setLayout(null);
    SixSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixSix.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SixSix.setBounds(170, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixSix);

    JPanel SevenSeven = new JPanel();
    SevenSeven.setLayout(null);
    SevenSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenSeven.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SevenSeven.setBounds(200, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenSeven);

    JPanel EightEight = new JPanel();
    EightEight.setLayout(null);
    EightEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightEight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    EightEight.setBounds(230, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightEight);

    JPanel OneThree = new JPanel();
    OneThree.setLayout(null);
    OneThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneThree.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    OneThree.setBounds(80, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneThree);

    JPanel TwoFour = new JPanel();
    TwoFour.setLayout(null);
    TwoFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoFour.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TwoFour.setBounds(110, 50, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(TwoFour);

    JPanel ThreeFive = new JPanel();
    ThreeFive.setLayout(null);
    ThreeFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeFive.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    ThreeFive.setBounds(140, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeFive);

    JPanel FourSix = new JPanel();
    FourSix.setLayout(null);
    FourSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourSix.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FourSix.setBounds(170, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourSix);

    JPanel FiveSeven = new JPanel();
    FiveSeven.setLayout(null);
    FiveSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveSeven.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FiveSeven.setBounds(200, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveSeven);

    JPanel SixEight = new JPanel();
    SixEight.setLayout(null);
    SixEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixEight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SixEight.setBounds(230, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixEight);

    JPanel OneFive = new JPanel();
    OneFive.setLayout(null);
    OneFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneFive.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    OneFive.setBounds(140, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneFive);

    JPanel TwoSix = new JPanel();
    TwoSix.setLayout(null);
    TwoSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoSix.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TwoSix.setBounds(170, 50, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(TwoSix);

    JPanel ThreeSeven = new JPanel();
    ThreeSeven.setLayout(null);
    ThreeSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeSeven.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    ThreeSeven.setBounds(200, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeSeven);

    JPanel FourEight = new JPanel();
    FourEight.setLayout(null);
    FourEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourEight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FourEight.setBounds(230, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourEight);

    JPanel OneSeven = new JPanel();
    OneSeven.setLayout(null);
    OneSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneSeven.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    OneSeven.setBounds(200, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneSeven);

    JPanel TwoEight = new JPanel();
    TwoEight.setLayout(null);
    TwoEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoEight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TwoEight.setBounds(230, 50, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(TwoEight);

    JPanel ThreeOne = new JPanel();
    ThreeOne.setLayout(null);
    ThreeOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeOne.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    ThreeOne.setBounds(20, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeOne);

    JPanel FourTwo = new JPanel();
    FourTwo.setLayout(null);
    FourTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourTwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FourTwo.setBounds(50, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourTwo);

    JPanel FiveThree = new JPanel();
    FiveThree.setLayout(null);
    FiveThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveThree.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FiveThree.setBounds(80, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveThree);

    JPanel SixFour = new JPanel();
    SixFour.setLayout(null);
    SixFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixFour.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SixFour.setBounds(110, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixFour);

    JPanel SevenFive = new JPanel();
    SevenFive.setLayout(null);
    SevenFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenFive.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SevenFive.setBounds(140, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenFive);

    JPanel EightSix = new JPanel();
    EightSix.setLayout(null);
    EightSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightSix.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    EightSix.setBounds(170, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightSix);

    JPanel FiveOne = new JPanel();
    FiveOne.setLayout(null);
    FiveOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveOne.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    FiveOne.setBounds(20, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveOne);

    JPanel SixTwo = new JPanel();
    SixTwo.setLayout(null);
    SixTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixTwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SixTwo.setBounds(50, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixTwo);

    JPanel SevenThree = new JPanel();
    SevenThree.setLayout(null);
    SevenThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenThree.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SevenThree.setBounds(80, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenThree);

    JPanel EightFour = new JPanel();
    EightFour.setLayout(null);
    EightFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightFour.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    EightFour.setBounds(110, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightFour);

    JPanel SevenOne = new JPanel();
    SevenOne.setLayout(null);
    SevenOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenOne.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    SevenOne.setBounds(20, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenOne);

    JPanel EightTwo = new JPanel();
    EightTwo.setLayout(null);
    EightTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightTwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    EightTwo.setBounds(50, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightTwo);

    JPanel OneTwo = new JPanel();
    OneTwo.setLayout(null);
    OneTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneTwo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    OneTwo.setBounds(50, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneTwo);

    JPanel OneFour = new JPanel();
    OneFour.setLayout(null);
    OneFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneFour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    OneFour.setBounds(110, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneFour);

    JPanel OneSix = new JPanel();
    OneSix.setLayout(null);
    OneSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneSix.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    OneSix.setBounds(170, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneSix);

    JPanel OneEight = new JPanel();
    OneEight.setLayout(null);
    OneEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    OneEight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    OneEight.setBounds(230, 20, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(OneEight);

    JPanel TwoOne = new JPanel();
    TwoOne.setBounds(20, 50, 30, 30);
    TwoOne.setLayout(null);
    TwoOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoOne.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //contentPane.add(TwoOne);



    JPanel TwoThree = new JPanel();
    TwoThree.setBounds(80, 50, 30, 30);
    TwoThree.setLayout(null);
    TwoThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoThree.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //contentPane.add(TwoThree);

    JPanel TwoFive = new JPanel();
    TwoFive.setBounds(140, 50, 30, 30);
    TwoFive.setLayout(null);
    TwoFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoFive.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //contentPane.add(TwoFive);

    JPanel TwoSeven = new JPanel();
    TwoSeven.setBounds(200, 50, 30, 30);
    TwoSeven.setLayout(null);
    TwoSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    TwoSeven.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //contentPane.add(TwoSeven);

    JPanel ThreeSix = new JPanel();
    ThreeSix.setLayout(null);
    ThreeSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeSix.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeSix.setBounds(170, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeSix);

    JPanel ThreeEight = new JPanel();
    ThreeEight.setLayout(null);
    ThreeEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeEight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeEight.setBounds(230, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeEight);

    JPanel ThreeFour = new JPanel();
    ThreeFour.setLayout(null);
    ThreeFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeFour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeFour.setBounds(110, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeFour);

    JPanel ThreeTwo = new JPanel();
    ThreeTwo.setLayout(null);
    ThreeTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeTwo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ThreeTwo.setBounds(50, 80, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(ThreeTwo);

    JPanel FourOne = new JPanel();
    FourOne.setLayout(null);
    FourOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourOne.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FourOne.setBounds(20, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourOne);

    JPanel FourThree = new JPanel();
    FourThree.setLayout(null);
    FourThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourThree.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FourThree.setBounds(80, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourThree);

    JPanel FourFive = new JPanel();
    FourFive.setLayout(null);
    FourFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourFive.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FourFive.setBounds(140, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourFive);

    JPanel FourSeven = new JPanel();
    FourSeven.setLayout(null);
    FourSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FourSeven.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FourSeven.setBounds(200, 110, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FourSeven);

    JPanel FiveEight = new JPanel();
    FiveEight.setLayout(null);
    FiveEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveEight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveEight.setBounds(230, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveEight);

    JPanel FiveTwo = new JPanel();
    FiveTwo.setLayout(null);
    FiveTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveTwo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveTwo.setBounds(50, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveTwo);

    JPanel FiveFour = new JPanel();
    FiveFour.setLayout(null);
    FiveFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveFour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveFour.setBounds(110, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveFour);

    JPanel FiveSix = new JPanel();
    FiveSix.setLayout(null);
    FiveSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveSix.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    FiveSix.setBounds(170, 140, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(FiveSix);

    JPanel SixOne = new JPanel();
    SixOne.setLayout(null);
    SixOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixOne.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SixOne.setBounds(20, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixOne);

    JPanel SixThree = new JPanel();
    SixThree.setLayout(null);
    SixThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixThree.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SixThree.setBounds(80, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixThree);

    JPanel SixFive = new JPanel();
    SixFive.setLayout(null);
    SixFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixFive.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SixFive.setBounds(140, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixFive);

    JPanel SixSeven = new JPanel();
    SixSeven.setLayout(null);
    SixSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SixSeven.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SixSeven.setBounds(200, 170, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SixSeven);

    JPanel SevenTwo = new JPanel();
    SevenTwo.setLayout(null);
    SevenTwo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenTwo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenTwo.setBounds(50, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenTwo);

    JPanel SevenFour = new JPanel();
    SevenFour.setLayout(null);
    SevenFour.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenFour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenFour.setBounds(110, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenFour);

    JPanel SevenSix = new JPanel();
    SevenSix.setLayout(null);
    SevenSix.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenSix.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenSix.setBounds(170, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenSix);

    JPanel SevenEight = new JPanel();
    SevenEight.setLayout(null);
    SevenEight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenEight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SevenEight.setBounds(230, 200, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(SevenEight);

    JPanel EightOne = new JPanel();
    EightOne.setLayout(null);
    EightOne.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightOne.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    EightOne.setBounds(20, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightOne);

    JPanel EightThree = new JPanel();
    EightThree.setLayout(null);
    EightThree.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightThree.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    EightThree.setBounds(80, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightThree);

    JPanel EightFive = new JPanel();
    EightFive.setLayout(null);
    EightFive.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightFive.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    EightFive.setBounds(140, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightFive);

    JPanel EightSeven = new JPanel();
    EightSeven.setLayout(null);
    EightSeven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    EightSeven.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    EightSeven.setBounds(200, 230, 30, 30);
    //contentPane.add(EightSeven);

        boardArray[0][0] = OneOne;
        boardArray[0][1] = OneTwo;
        boardArray[0][2] = OneThree;
        boardArray[0][3] = OneFour;
        boardArray[0][4] = OneFive;
        boardArray[0][5] = OneSix;
        boardArray[0][6] = OneSeven;
        boardArray[0][7] = OneEight;

        boardArray[1][0] = TwoOne;
        boardArray[1][1] = TwoTwo;
        boardArray[1][2] = TwoThree;
        boardArray[1][3] = TwoFour;
        boardArray[1][4] = TwoFive;
        boardArray[1][5] = TwoSix;
        boardArray[1][6] = TwoSeven;
        boardArray[1][7] = TwoEight;

        boardArray[2][0] = ThreeOne;
        boardArray[2][1] = ThreeTwo;
        boardArray[2][2] = ThreeThree;
        boardArray[2][3] = ThreeFour;
        boardArray[2][4] = ThreeFive;
        boardArray[2][5] = ThreeSix;
        boardArray[2][6] = ThreeSeven;
        boardArray[2][7] = ThreeEight;

        boardArray[3][0] = FourOne;
        boardArray[3][1] = FourTwo;
        boardArray[3][2] = FourThree;
        boardArray[3][3] = FourFour;
        boardArray[3][4] = FourFive;
        boardArray[3][5] = FourSix;
        boardArray[3][6] = FourSeven;
        boardArray[3][7] = FourEight;

        boardArray[4][0] = FiveOne;
        boardArray[4][1] = FiveTwo;
        boardArray[4][2] = FiveThree;
        boardArray[4][3] = FiveFour;
        boardArray[4][4] = FiveFive;
        boardArray[4][5] = FiveSix;
        boardArray[4][6] = FiveSeven;
        boardArray[4][7] = FiveEight;

        boardArray[5][0] = SixOne;
        boardArray[5][1] = SixTwo;
        boardArray[5][2] = SixThree;
        boardArray[5][3] = SixFour;
        boardArray[5][4] = SixFive;
        boardArray[5][5] = SixSix;
        boardArray[5][6] = SixSeven;
        boardArray[5][7] = SixEight;

        boardArray[6][0] = SevenOne;
        boardArray[6][1] = SevenTwo;
        boardArray[6][2] = SevenThree;
        boardArray[6][3] = SevenFour;
        boardArray[6][4] = SevenFive;
        boardArray[6][5] = SevenSix;
        boardArray[6][6] = SevenSeven;
        boardArray[6][7] = SevenEight;

        boardArray[7][0] = EightOne;
        boardArray[7][1] = EightTwo;
        boardArray[7][2] = EightThree;
        boardArray[7][3] = EightFour;
        boardArray[7][4] = EightFive;
        boardArray[7][5] = EightSix;
        boardArray[7][6] = EightSeven;
        boardArray[7][7] = EightEight;

        String SquareName;
        String boardArrayName[];
        boardArrayName = new String[]{"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight"};

        for(int firstParameter = 0; firstParameter < 8; firstParameter++){

            for(int secondParameter = 0; secondParameter < 8; secondParameter++){

                SquareName = boardArrayName[firstParameter] + boardArrayName[secondParameter];
                contentPane.add(boardArray[firstParameter][secondParameter]);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: unrelated to your question, but why Not just 1 JPanel with a GridLayout  instead of the use of nxn null layouts?

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I want to be able to put the pieces on the board afterwards hence the 64 JPanels

Comment: Use an array or List of some kind to maintain a reference to each panel. You can't dynamically create variable names. Avoid null layouts, you don't control the differences in rendering pipelines which change the amount of space a component might need to be properly laid out. You could achieve a board like appearance using a GridLayout or GridBagLayout depending on your ultimate needs

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Map to track each name - panel mapping, for instance the field panelMap in this example:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

    public class ChessBoardPractice extends JFrame {

        private final Map<String, JPanel>   panelMap    = new LinkedHashMap<String, JPanel>();

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        final ChessBoardPractice frame = new ChessBoardPractice();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public ChessBoardPractice() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
            final JPanel boardArray[][] = new JPanel[8][8];
            final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
                    boardArray[i][j] = panel;
                    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        panel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        panel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }
            }

            final String boardArrayName[] = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight" };
            for (int firstParameter = 0; firstParameter < 8; firstParameter++) {
                for (int secondParameter = 0; secondParameter < 8; secondParameter++) {
                    final String name = boardArrayName[firstParameter] + boardArrayName[secondParameter];
                    contentPane.add(boardArray[firstParameter][secondParameter]);
                    panelMap.put(name, boardArray[firstParameter][secondParameter]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(panelMap);
        }
    }
```